# Add Tags to MediaWiki and showing a tag cloud on the front page?

Tags: tags, mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to add "tags" like in delicious to mediawiki pages and then show a tag cloud on the front page using this.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few extensions along these lines:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Tag_cloud_extensions

Answer (score 2):

Extension:Nimbus can add the cloud to the front page or any page.
In the discussion page http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:Nimbus#Nimbus_at_Sidebar you can find how to add it to the side bar.